# How to fix the crash program loop

Tags: python, loops

The program is to counts your change and reports the total amount and it run in a loop. This where the problem start the program ask the user for their name and if the user does not enter a name  the program should quit. When inserting a name it started to crash.

```
def calculateChanges( quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies):
    twentyFive = .25
    tens = .10
    fives = .05
    ones = .01
    twentyFive = int(twentyFive) * int(quarters)
    tens = int(tens) * int(dimes)
    fives = int(fives) * int(nickels)
    ones = int(ones) * int(pennies)
    combineAll = twentyFive + tens + fives + ones
    return combineAll

theName = input('What is your name (Return/Enter to quit)?')

while theName == theName:
    theFirst = input('How many quarter do you have? ')
    theSecond = input('How many dimes do you have? ')
    theThird = input('How many nickels do you have? ')
    theLast = input('How many pennies do you have? ')

    justTotal = calculateChanges(theFirst, theSecond, theThird, theLast)
    print('All counted,',theName, 'has: $'+ str(justTotal))

    else:
        print('Bye')
```

Answer (score 0):

`theName == theName` is always true and thus you never exit the loop